# What does the given part of a formula do in r?

Tags: r, random-forest

So I'm building a random forest, and using something like this to do so (from the aptly named randomForest package):

```
rfmodel<-randomForest(formula=predictthis ~ .,data=train.df, ...)
```

The part I'm wondering about, and I've googled and used the documentation to no avail, is what the "~ ." part is doing? I just know I'm supposed to use it I guess since the builder fails without it, but you must be able to put other things there since why bother including it as a choice if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the whole formula    `predictthis ~ .`
You should read this as  predictthis   as a function of everything else.
Where you have .  you could list out a subset of the variables explicitly. There is a small language  for how to express what you are predicting as a function of what.   Try `?formula`